# Error in installing anchor?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js, rust, rpc

I don't know what is the problem here ?!

[image]

Comment: Are you using the anchor-lang docs installation guide https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/installation ? Do you have the prerequisites installed? Solana, rust, node ...

Comment: hi. yes i am using anchor docs and i have installed solana, nodejs, rust. but i don't know why i am facing with this problem!

Comment: could you share the versions for you Rust and Solana. 

also, instead of images, could you share the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Update to the latest version of Rust using `rustup`

Run `cargo clean` and try installing again.